# Using Infura, how do I know the deployed contract address

Tags: web3js, infura

I'm doing this with web3.js and infura.

Is there a way I can know the contract address?

```
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(myContractAbi);

let deploy = myContract.deploy({
  data: '0x' + myContractByteCode
  arguments: [ ]
});

// get the number of transactions sent so far so we can create a fresh nonce
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress).then(txCount => {
  const rawTransaction = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(500000),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice * 1e9), // gasPrice Gwei
    from: fromAddress,
    value: '0x00',
    data: deploy.encodeABI()
  };

  const privateKeyHex = new Buffer(privateKey, 'hex')
  const tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);
  tx.sign(privateKeyHex);
  const serializedTx = tx.serialize().toString('hex');

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx, (err, result) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
});
```

console.log(result); returns TXID

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx, (err, result) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(result);
  }
}).on('receipt', (receipt) => {
  console.log(receipt.contractAddress);
});
```